# How can I improve my tracking of light and light sources?

Tags: dnd-5e, gm-techniques, vision-and-light

At the moment, I largely forget about light and light sources in my games. I assume that my players can see everything around them without stopping to think about whether it should actually be pitch black in this dungeon.

What techniques can I use to improve my tracking of light and light sources?

Comment: Might be duplicate of: [I keep forgetting about lighting in the heat of a session. How do I remember my notes?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/63644/23064)

Comment: Is this more about tracking location, boundaries, and general effects of lighting (it seems like that to me), or is this about tracking expiry/lifetime of light sources like torches and lamp oil refills (what I thought when we originally discussed the question)?

Comment: @SevenSidedDie It was originally intended to be about both. However, it seems to be a duplicate of the other one only in regard to tracking location, boundaries, etc, and not in tears of light sources. When I get time later, I will edit the question to differentiate it from the other, and maybe practice some SE thread necromancy with my current answer.