# What are the Limits of the line of sight requirement in spells?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, familiars, line-of-sight

As wizard, would it be possible to use your familiar's line of sight as your own for spells such as Mirage Arcane which has a range of sight? Would You be able to use a telescope or spyglass to use that spell?

Comment: Also a bit related: "[Is it legal to cast a spell with a range of Sight on someone you can see, but without a clear path?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/98826)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A familiar’s line of sight counts as your own when you are seeing from its eyes, and this works for spells that require line of sight, so yes for a familiar.

Their is no telescopes in RAW, so I’ll talk about spyglass. A spyglass does not increase how far you can see by the book, instead it “magnifies objects to twice their size, like a magnifying glass. So for this portion, I’d have to say no, not by RAW.