# Does looking at a gaze attack indirectly still trigger the effect?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic, bard, summoner, eidolon

This question is similar to [this one](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/134167/34872), but with Pathfinder rules in mind.

More specifically, my group is up against a creature that does damage when it looks at you. Our bard ran away, but can still cast [Fearsome Duplicate](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/f/fearsome-duplicate/) through which she could still see the monster in question.

Does this form of vision happen to trigger the specific fort save that would result from its gaze attack?

Similarly, would an summoner be affected by using [Bond Senses](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/summoner/#TOC-Bond-Senses-Su-) with his eidolon, looking at a gaze attack?

What about [Scrying](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/scrying/) or [Sentry Skull](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/sentry-skull/)?

I know Perseus can view Medusa through a mirror, but magic vision seems like it might be more closely linked with your brain?

Comment: Does this creature have a name? Gaze attacks may work differently than whatever ability the creature had.

Comment: @ShadowKras hound of tindalos. Sorry I've been avoiding looking at the page since I'm a player. Would've linked it otherwise, but I also want this question to be generic enough to still be useful in other situations

Comment: Alright, just had to be sure its not something else and follows the same rules as other gaze attacks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### It does not

As described under the [Gaze](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/universal-monster-rules/#Gaze_Su) universal monster ability:

> Only looking **directly** at a creature with a gaze attack leaves an opponent vulnerable.

Not only that, but nearly all gaze attacks have a limited range (usually 30 ft), which must be met for the saving throw to be required. If your character is outside of that area, the gaze attack has no effect at all.

As for [Scrying](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic#TOC-Divination) methods, those are treated as a separate sensory organ, and not exactly a replacement for your eyes. So, any effect that works through the eyes shouldn't work at all while using a scrying ability.

> Scrying: A scrying spell creates an invisible magical sensor that sends you information. Unless noted otherwise, the sensor has the same powers of sensory acuity that you possess. This level of acuity includes any spells or effects that target you, but not spells or effects that emanate from you. The sensor, however, is treated as a **separate, independent sensory organ** of yours, and thus functions normally even if you have been blinded or deafened, or otherwise suffered sensory impairment.

However, reading the text of [Fearsome Duplicate](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/f/fearsome-duplicate/), I would say that your copy would get destroyed as soon as the creature looks at it if this gaze attack is one that does damage, such as the gaze from a [Hound of Tindalos](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/outsiders/hound-of-tindalos/). But otherwise, a petrifying gaze, for example, shouldn't have much effect on it.

> The duplicate immediately winks out of existence if it is hit by an attack or in the area of a damaging effect, or if it moves beyond the maximum range of the spell.

Comment: An excellent answer as always! would the duplicate get a saving throw though?

Comment: I wouldn't say so. It doesn't get a reflex against a fireball, it simply disapears.