# Is the sensor created by Scrying tangible?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, divination

The spell *[scrying](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/scrying)* states:

> ... the spell creates an **invisible** sensor within 10 feet of the target. You can see and hear through the sensor as if you were there. The sensor moves with the target, remaining within 10 feet of it for the duration. A creature that can see invisible **objects** sees the sensor as a luminous orb about the size of your fist.

The sensor is:

1. **Invisible**, but not explicitly intangible
2. **An object**, because it can be seen by a creature whose only talent is the ability to see invisible objects

Objects in 5e, as far as I know, possess a corporeal form, and can be touched unless otherwise specified. RAI, it's not clear to me whether the sensor is supposed to be totally formless and therefore nearly undetectable, or possessing of a form, and therefore flawed in a way that might unintentionally provide some information to the party being scried, for example when someone bumps into it. But I am not here to ask about RAI.

**RAW, is the sensor created by *scrying* tangible?** I'm aware of [this answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/169791/what-can-be-done-to-a-scrying-sensor), however I note two key differences that I believe may sway the RAW answer:

1. The *scrying* sensor lacks the text "otherwise can't be interacted with",
2. The *clairvoyance* sensor cannot be seen by creatures who can see invisible objects.

Comment: Actually, the [Clairovojance](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/clairvoyance) sensor can be seen :"A creature that can see the sensor (such as a creature benefiting from see invisibility or truesight) sees a luminous, intangible orb about the size of your fist." I believe that actually the Q&A you linked is not so different from what you're asking...