# Good detectible magic sensor for low-level players

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, magic-items, story

I'm planning a campaign in which the players stop a goblinoid host led by a wizard. The plan is for the players to help stop the host along with other conscripted adventurers. Along the way, however, the PCs will encounter goblins who were made into sorcerers intentionally as an experiment in creating sorcerers. I want to hint to the players that the goblins were sorcerers by design rather than chance by leaving a magic sensor for the players to find, like an *arcane eye* spell in its sensory abilities. The problem is that it may not occur to the players to cast *detect magic* to find a sensor, so I'm trying to find a sensor that would be visible and easy for the players to "stumble upon" after the fight with the goblin sorcerer. Does anyone know of a good magical sensor that fits what I'm looking for?

Comment: I’m not entirely sure what you’re asking for here. Are you looking for a magic item that the players would find and determine is some sort of scrying device? Are you asking if such an item exists?

Comment: Yeah, there really isn't enough information here for us to provide an answer and what information there is is vague and confusing. If you want it to act as an *Arcane Eye* then why isn't the *Arcane Eye* spell enough, just make it visible and it's duration permanent or something? How is the sensor supposed to hint that the goblins are sorcerers by design? What exactly *are* you looking for in this sensor? What do you want the sensor to do exactly? **Also** please note that we don't do "homebrew this for me" type questions so if you're asking us to come up with a sensor for you then we can't.

Comment: Has the good old note on a desk gone out of fashion?

Comment: The sensor created by Scrying CAN be felt, although it is invisible: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/169791/what-can-be-done-to-a-scrying-sensor Perhaps the plucky adv.s happen to bump into an invisible sphere during the course of searching the place?