# Can an NPC use the Teleport spell to affect an object they can see with the Scrying spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, targeting, teleportation

[*Teleport*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/teleport) shows that it has a range of 10 feet and uses the following language:

> This spell instantly transports you and up to eight willing creatures
>   of your choice that you can see within range, or a single object that
>   you can see within range, to a destination you select. If you target
>   an object, it must be able to fit entirely inside a 10-foot cube, and
>   it can’t be held or carried by an unwilling creature.

I want to have a non-present NPC who is using the *scrying* spell to spy on the characters' location to use the *teleport* spell on an object in the room the characters are in. Is this possible as long as the object is within 10 feet of the sensor created by the *scrying* spell, or is that not possible?

TLDR; can I cast the *teleport* spell through the sensor created with the *scrying* spell, using the sensor’s location as the base for target range?

Comment: I understand it's probably scary to have people watching you from far away but did you perhaps mean the *Scry* spell? :)

Comment: Helpful: "[What counts as a target for a spell?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/152115)". Related: "[Is it possible to attack enemies through a scrying sensor?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/97951)".

Answer (score 22, accepted):

## *Scrying* does not expand spell ranges

The two restrictions, that the target must be within range and that you must be able to see it are separate and both must be satisfied. "See within range" is not a requirement on the clarity with which you see them and thus does not translate to "see as if you were within range".

So you will not be able to fetch an item from a far away location like this. The problem is further compounded by the restriction that you must have a clear path to anything you target (PHB 204).

So *scrying* will not help in *teleport*ing an item away, but it would help in targeting the spell if you would teleport something to the place under observation (making familiarity "very familiar").

Answer (score 2):

Without looking up the specifics of the spells, and based on what I read here...

I would be open to an argument that as long as the item to *teleport* is within 10 feet, one could use *scry* to get around a line of sight issue.

For instance, if the NPC is immediately upstairs (and probably more or less directly over the object), or next door, *scry* could let the NPC 'see' the object and teleport it out of the room. It won't go very far! But in this situation, *scry* and *teleport* can be used together.

And from a play perspective, it suggests the NPC is close by and the PCs can now have fun trying to run the NPC down and get the object back.

Comment: Note the restrictions on "willing" targets: even for an object, it can't be held/carried by an "unwilling" creature.  But yes, good point about using Scry to see through walls and stuff within Teleport's range limit.

Comment: Indeed, if it's being held. If the PCs are just examining it on the table, however...