# Can I use Unearthed Arcana Mystic's Nomad's Gate to drop enemies from the sky?

Tags: dnd-5e, unearthed-arcana, teleportation, mystic

[Here is the most recent version (v3) of the Mystic class from Unearthed Arcana.](https://media.wizards.com/2017/dnd/downloads/UAMystic3.pdf)

One of the Nomadic Step discipline's psionic effects is Nomad's Gate:

> ***Nomad’s Gate (7 psi; conc., 1 hr.).*** As an action, you create a 5-foot cube of dim, gray light within 5 feet of you. You create an identical cube at any point of your choice within 1 mile that you have viewed within the past 24 hours. Until your concentration ends, anyone entering one of the cubes immediately teleports to the other one, appearing in an unoccupied space next to it. The teleportation fails if there is no space for the creature to appear in.

Does this mean I can create the second cube a mile up in the sky, and the first on on top of an enemy, or as a readied action - in response to an enemy approaching me, to effectively drop them from 5000 ft up in the sky (taking them out of the fight for a minute and dealing 20d6 damage from the fall)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Only if the enemy *enters* the cube

Choosing the cube on top of the target wouldn't work. The creature has to enter the cube. Otherwise, as long as you have the sky 5000 feet above you, then yes, the cube will teleport the entering creature into the sky and it will fall.

### Have I seen that patch of sky?

[This question about how far you can see](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/65263/how-far-can-you-see-targets-lip-reading-etc) addresses visibility concerns and on a clear day (or even a rainy one) you should be fine. I see no added limitations on the detailed viewing required for the area you choose. "View" is simply a synonym of see.

### Does it take a minute?

If you use the variant rules for fall times from Xanathar's Guide to Everything then yes. It is 500 feet per round which totals 10 rounds or 1 minute. Otherwise, it is unclear how long it takes to fall, but it is likely about the same if we assume gravity functions similar to Earth.

This question details falling rates: [How far do you fall per turn?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/75954/how-far-do-you-fall-per-turn)

Comment: Might also be worth addressing whether you can reasonably be interpreted to "have viewed" a point 5000 feet in the air...

Comment: well considering i just need to have seen it within the past 24 hours, i can even do that inside. 

Also, wouldnt them being inside the cube open up some abuse? Ignoring the fact that grapples or melee would have to visibly enter (at least in part - but combat technically doesnt matter like that) 

On a more actually rules basis. If one gets placed on you or an enemy incidentally due to invisibility, one could stay inside and prevent use for any other creature as they cant enter the square.