# House ruling Darkness Blindnes and Obscured

Tags: dnd-5e, house-rules, vision-and-light

**Background**

I am DMing Curse Of Stradh - and there is a lot of Fog in Barovia. The party have characters with and without dark-vision. I am not really happy with how light, darkness and obscurement work with the blinded condition, nor with how Fog-Cloud (L1) and Darkness (L2) spells seem to work and how little difference there is between them in 5E RAW. I would expect them to do more, and Darkness to be stronger than Fog-Cloud since it is L2.

I would like feedback on some house rules I am considering.
Specifically if there are some game-braking problems or better solutions.

**Concerns**

**1.** A heavily obscured area blocks vision and effectively makes you suffer from blindness condition if looking into it. This seems reasonable until you realize this means you cannot see through normal darkness and see a guard with a torch, nor the moon and stars.

Vision and Light RAW with errata

> A heavily obscured area--such as darkness, opaque fog, or dense
> foliage--blocks vision entirely. A creature effectively suffers from
> the blinded condition when trying to see something in that area."

Blinded RAW

> A blinded creature can’t see and automatically fails any ability check
> that requires sight. Attack rolls against the creature have advantage,
> and the creature’s attack rolls have disadvantage.

Darkness RAW

> Darkness creates a heavily obscured area.

**2.** The fact that two fighters in a dark cellar has both advantage and disadvantage (canceling each other as per Sage Advice), seemed odd but acceptable. That is until I considered Darkness and Fog Cloud spells.

All else being the same, what is the point of casting the spell? I can attack and be attacked normally, or waste an action and 2nd level spell slot to cast darkness, and then we can attack each other with advantage and disadvantage canceling out. It makes no difference if I step out of darkness, attack, and then back in, or toggle Darkness on and off by covering a coin with Darkness. What will Fog Cloud and Darkness spell achieve?

Admittedly if I have disadvantage or enemy has advantage already, or I am being targeted by "a target you can see" spell Darkness will help me remove advantage of disadvantage for everyone, but that is rather situational - Blur or Mirror Image (Shatter?) seem much better than Darkness for a second level spell slot.

(Special circumstances like having devil sight or Blind fighter feat obviously change things)

**3.** If I am in a heavily obscured area (Fog, Foliage) I am effectively blinded. That may be true for someone a bit of a distance away, but what kind of fog or heavy smoke makes me unable to realize someone is standing right beside me? They may find it easier to hide, but even the heaviest fog is not the same as wearing a blindfold at short distances.

RAW Vision and Light

> A given area might be lightly or heavily obscured. In a lightly
> obscured area, such as dim light, patchy fog, or moderate foliage,
> creatures have disadvantage on Wisdom (Perception) checks that rely on
> sight.
>
> A heavily obscured area--such as darkness, opaque fog, or dense
> foliage--blocks vision entirely. A creature effectively suffers from
> the blinded condition when trying to see something in that area.
>
> The presence or absence of light in an environment creates three
> categories of illumination: bright light, dim light, and darkness.
>
> Bright light lets most creatures see normally. Even gloomy days
> provide bright light, as do torches, lanterns, fires, and other
> sources of illumination within a specific radius.
>
> Dim light, also called shadows, creates a lightly obscured area. An
> area of dim light is usually a boundary between a source of bright
> light, such as a torch, and surrounding darkness. The soft light of
> twilight and dawn also counts as dim light. A particularly brilliant
> full moon might bathe the land in dim light.
>
> Darkness creates a heavily obscured area. Characters face darkness
> outdoors at night (even most moonlit nights), within the confines of
> an unlit dungeon or a subterranean vault, or in an area of magical
> darkness.

**4.** I find the difference between Dark-Vision and Non-Darkvision characters is a bit OPed and awkward, even if you remember that dim-light gives disadvantage on perception. If the human or halfling rogue carry a torch no one will be stealth-ing a lot, not even all the other races with dark-vision. So either no one can sneak well or we give everyone dark-vision with gear if needed. Neither seem much fun. If everyone has dark-vision we just cancelled darkness. And if you have ever been in the woods at night far from civilizations lights, you know how spooky that is. And I want things that go bump in the night to be scary.

**House-rules I am considering**

**H1.** Add to the blinded condition that you only get advantage if you can see (or something similar) blinded target.

> A blinded creature can’t see and automatically fails any ability check that requires sight.

*if you can see it (or something equivalent like echolocation blindsight)*, your

> attack rolls against the creature have advantage. The creature’s attack rolls have disadvantage.

This fixes Darkness and Fog cloud not doing a lot. If you hide in area of effect you and your enemy has disadvantage. You can step out and attack with neither advantage of disadvantage (or turn Darkness on/off by covering it).

(After having this idea I discovered others did too, but that does not make it bad https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ALhcjHnFHW8&t=663s)

**H2** Switch cause and effect of light and obscurement. I want to fix it so we can see through normal darkness and see campfires, the moon and stars at night. I also want to make fog in Barovia a bit more of a level playing field between regular vision and dark-vision characters and get that feeling of "something in the fog is sneaking up on us". I also want there to be a difference in effect between the Darkness spell and the Fog Cloud spell.

*Bright light: Everyone sees normally*

*Dim light: Creatures have disadvantage on Wisdom (Perception) checks that rely on sight (FKA Lightly Obscured).*

*Darkness: A creature effectively suffers from the blinded condition when trying to see something in that area. You need to pick square to attack with disadvantage. Note It does NOT block light/vision, illuminated not-in-darkness things are visible from darkness or beyond.*

*Treat a lightly obscured area such as patchy fog, or moderate foliage, like Dim Light*

*Treat a heavily obscured area such as opaque fog, or dense foliage, like Dim light within 5 feet and Darkness past 5 feet. Past 5 feet it blocks vision, including dark-vision, entirely.**

Now the rogue in the (non magical) darkness can see and attack the guard carrying the touch, in this case with advantage since guard is effectively blinded trying to see rogue in darkness beyond the light. And we have a moon and stars again - that should make the lycanthropes happy

**H3** Dark-Vision

*Dark-Vision treats darkness like Dim Light for 60 (or 120) feet. Past 5 feet in the monochromatic dim light you have disadvantage on attacks (but you do not need to guess square like you may have to if blinded - you can see there is something, but not well). Note heavy obscured blocks dark-vision.*

Now Darkvision is less OP compared to regular vision, but rewards sneaking up on someone and shanking them, not just shooting them down from the dark, and once a fight starts dark-visioned archers may hang back but like the illumination their humans friends cast on their foes, granting them advantage rather than disadvantage shooting from the dark.

**H4** Darkness Spell:
Some feel that RAW implies you can see out of and through Darkness spell area since it only says dark vision cannot, not regular vision. I was tempted to use this to make the spell do something under RAW erattaed Blindness rules. However, that would grant an attacker in darkness advantage against an unsuspecting foe that cannot see him, while also having foe have disadvantage - that seems as strong as 2nd level Blindness spell but for a mobile area that last longer and has no save. Since blindness rule change makes Darkness Spell "work" again, lets be specific and say it blocks light, normal vision, and darkvision. Maybe it is an area of anti-photons that magically "eats" all light.

> Magical darkness spreads from a point you choose within range to fill a 15-foot-radius sphere for the duration. The darkness spreads around corners.

*It blocks light, normal vision, and dark vision* (replaces "creature with darkvision can’t see through this darkness")

> and nonmagical light can’t illuminate it. If the point you choose is on an object you are holding or one that isn’t being worn or carried, the darkness emanates from the object and moves with it. Completely covering the source of the darkness with an opaque object, such as a bowl or a helm, blocks the darkness.
> If any of this spell’s area overlaps with an area of light created by a spell of 2nd level or lower, the spell that created the light is dispelled.

Comment: Voting to close for “needs more focus”, you present several distinct, but related problems, then present four different house rules without really asking much of a question besides “general feedback”. We don’t do well with general feedback, at least not without a specific problem to solve, and you’ve got several problems to solve and several house rules to look at here without clear direction for doing so.

Comment: @Thomas Markov
I am at a loss to how I would focus it more. As you say, the problems and solutions I am asking for feedback on are related. There is an interdependence.
"We don’t do well with general feedback, at least not without a specific problem to solve" I am sorry to hear that.
I guess my problem is that I need others insight on how my "fixes" may fail / have unintended side effects.
I realize feedback to such unfocused issues may be difficult, but I'd be happy for less than perfect 2nd opinions on problems my proposed house rules may have, rather than just experiment on players.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov I cleartified my question / Request beyond "feedback" I hope that helps

Comment: We prefer to keep question posts focused on a single question, and four different house rules is four different questions.

Comment: OK Thomas. I can split it up I guess, but I am not sure it will make any sense afterwards since they are related. I'll give it a try tomorrow. Can I link questions? Perhaps
Q1: Blindness condition. Q2: Based on <link Q1> Not seeing through darkness. Q3 link Q1 Q2 addressing dark-vision.
I am guessing a general question "how to fix vision and light" is not the way to go.

Comment: @OrionSteel I had a similar issue asking a question if an ASI on your main damage stat is generally better for damage than feats getting shut down as needs focus, and went on to break it down feat by feat. Asking a bunch of related questions then resulted in initial downvotes on the questions, but at least they did not get shut down for “needs focus”. I think you put a lot of thought and work into your question, and the issues you are trying to solve *are* worth having a good house rule for.

Comment: Note also that many/most of your concerns are well known and addressed by other questions on the stack. Although you should be researching them to the extent of your ability, separating them allows other users to more easily give you helpful pointers. For example, your concern 1, that normal light can't pass through normal darkness, is addressed [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/96510/does-using-a-light-in-darkness-make-a-sneaking-rogue-obvious-to-monsters), for example. Normal light in fact does pass through normal darkness, such that you can see the guard with his torch.

Comment: @GroodytheHobgoblin Thanks

Comment: @Kirt Well I did try searching first - I guess my googlefoo was weak or I rolled a 1 in perception. Now I feel silly spending a couple of hours trying to write a clear question and explanation - in particular since it was closed before I even had a chance to rewrite it. TBH I think I'll just give up on this forum. Waste of time trying to ask a question it seems. If Groody's experience is a guide it may not be closed just down voted into oblivion if I waste time splitting it apart. But thanks to those of you who commented.

Comment: @Kirt Actually your link does not address the fact that RAW implies light cannot cross darkness,  but it would help the rogue sneaking while holding a light in the question - until he got close enough monster was in the dim light. So there is that.
I am still not finding questions addressing my concerns either - if anyone has any links  please leave in comment.

Comment: @OrionSteel FWIW you can edit a question even after it is closed, and doing so will enter it into a re-opening review queue.

Comment: @OrionSteel If you read Clearly Toughpik's [answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/96578/23547) and that question, they quote the DMG "Bright light in an environment of total darkness can be visible for miles".  That to me implies that a source of light will not illuminate normal darkness beyond its stated range, but can pass through normal darkness - as one would expect from the real world.

Comment: @Kirt Getting us to the point of my question / house rule because RAW also says "A heavily obscured area--such as _darkness_, opaque fog, or dense foliage--_blocks vision entirely_" so I cannot see through darkness (regular or magical) apparently yet also RAW "Bright light in an environment of total darkness can be visible for miles"

Comment: @Kirt said "FWIW you can edit a question even after it is closed, and doing so will enter it into a re-opening review" - good to know. I don't think I'll bother though given Groody the hobgoblin's experience when he tried. Not worth my time.

Comment: @Kirt Using the general to specific rule, I guess light can travel through darkness (natural or magical apparently) but vision cannot. So I can see stars and the moonlight, and the guards torch after all, but not the guard since vision is blocked entirely.

Comment: @OrionSteel welcome to the stack, where the militant few don't like complicated questions. This is a perfectly reasonable question that lots of people struggle with, can we as a community not please just understand that in one place, instead of understanding it in 10 different places and then blaming people for not finding each separate and unlinked question? I left this site after seeing some of the hassle you put Groody through, came back and immediately disenfranchised again. You are making this site worse than it could be.

Comment: @OrionSteel Clearly Toughpick's answer also quotes the errata to the PHB, which says "A heavily obscured area doesn’t blind you, but you are effectively blinded when you try to see something obscured by it."  To me, this means that the image of the guard (in the light of the torch) passes through the normal darkness, and both can be seen on the other side, and that when RAW says that darkness _blocks vision entirely_, it means only of the things actually within the darkness.  At least, that is how I would interpret it.

Comment: @OrionSteel If you would like to see a more comprehensive analysis of your concern 1 (how mundane darkness actually works), I encourage you to either edit this question so it includes only that (and save the other parts for reposting as their own questions), or open another question that is just a copy-paste of 1.  One you are satisfied that you have a RAW understanding of mundane darkness, that understanding could affect your homebrew suggestions for dealing with the 'problem', if you think one still exists.

Comment: @SeriousBri Thanks